# How to serve static content in DXA 2.2 .net without a Localization?

Tags: dxa, sites-9.6

I'm running Tridion 9.6, DXA 2.2.9 .net and the GraphQL providers to CD Services. Topology Manager is installed and configured for both hostnames and contexts.

I have a Publication identified by hostname and context (`/en`). I do **not** have a Publication mapped to the root context (`/`).

DXA works fine for requests to the `hostname/en` URLs. However, I can't seem to serve any static files that are in the root of the website (e.g. `/js/main.js`). These are all static files on the filesystem. Instead, I get error `Sdl.Web.Common.DxaUnknownLocalizationException: No matching Localization found for URL` coming from the `StaticContentModule`:

```
   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in C:\DXAGitHub\dxa-suite\repositories\dxa-web-application-dotnet\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:28
   Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs) in C:\DXAGitHub\dxa-suite\repositories\dxa-web-application-dotnet\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:121
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +223
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +220
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +94
```

Looking at the source code (https://github.com/RWS/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/5c24bcc990f53a7357362b94e2526fd05a3f710b/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Statics/StaticContentModule.cs#L123), I see it needs a Localization object.

There is no Publication that maps to the root of the website, therefore there is no Localization available.

How can one server static content in this case?

Notes:

- Adding a Publication for context / is not feasible.
- I implemented an `IUnknownLocalizationHandler`, but that is only used here in the StaticContentModule (link: https://github.com/RWS/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/5c24bcc990f53a7357362b94e2526fd05a3f710b/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Statics/StaticContentModule.cs#L62), so it doesn't help.
- I tried excluding the path from routes `routes.IgnoreRoute("js/{*pathInfo}")`, but still the HttpModule is called.

How can I prevent some URL patterns be handled by the `StaticContentModule`?

So far, all I can see is modify the open source `StaticContentModule` to allow it requests when there is no `Localization` object.

Looking forward to your thoughts and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting! Indeed, in general, DXA assumes that all HTTP requests can be mapped to a Localization/Publication.

However, there is indeed the `IUnknownLocalizationHandler` extension point to be able to determine what should happen if a Localization cannot be resolved in the regular way. This was introduced for a specific use case (Just-In-Time provisioning) and apparently it can't cover your scenario.

Alternatively, you could look into creating your own [ILocalizationResolver](https://github.com/RWS/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/5c24bcc990f53a7357362b94e2526fd05a3f710b/Sdl.Web.Common/Interfaces/ILocalizationResolver.cs) implementation (based on the default one).

Or you could create your own HttpModule (which runs before the StaticContentModule) which sets a dummy `WebRequestContext.Localization` for these "localizationless" URLs)

Comment: Thanks Rick, -- I accept this as answer. I ended up using my own IUnknownLocalizationHandler implementation to create a dummy Localization and then extend (lobotomize) the StaticContentModule to use use the dummy Localization in case of a Location-less request. I use this together with some Regular Expression patterns defined in AppConfig to only serve the content if the URL matches the regex.